# How to build pnacl toolchain

Tags: build, google-nativeclient, toolchain

My goal is to make some new function to pnacl toolchain. Before I doing so, I think I should build the pnacl toolchain successfully first.

[11/04 Update]

Finally it works. Some package(bison, byacc, flex) I did't install and caused this problem.

[11/03 Update]

I use ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64 as my system

Also, ubuntu-12.04.5-desktop-amd64 is now testing [11/03 updated]

I've followed the step of [the document](http://www.chromium.org/nativeclient/pnacl/developing-pnacl#TOC-Toolchain-Development) all the way. Everything goes just fine until I run the toolchain_build_pnacl script

So I add the new error message here :

if I run the script using gcc to compile

> toolchain_build/toolchain_build_pnacl.py --gcc --verbose --sync --clobber
>   --install toolchain/linux_x86/pnacl_newlib

then the following error message is

> gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../src/binutils/gold 
>   -I../../../src/binutils/gold -I../../../src/binutils/gold/../include - I../../../src/binutils/gold/../elfcpp -DLOCALEDIR="\"/share/locale\""
>   -DBINDIR="\"/bin\"" -DTOOLBINDIR="\"/arm-pc-nacl/bin\"" -DTOOLLIBDIR="\"/arm-pc-nacl/lib\""   -W -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wshadow -Werror -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -frandom-seed=yyscript.o -Wno-extended-offsetof -Wno-absolute-value -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-const-variable -Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration -Wno-unused-private-field -Wno-format-security -MT yyscript.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/yyscript.Tpo -c -o yyscript.o yyscript.c yyscript.c:1:1: error: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Werror=return-type] yyscript.c:1:1: error: function
>
> declaration isn’t a prototype [-Werror=strict-prototypes] cc1: error:
>   unrecognized command line option "-Wno-unused-private-field" [-Werror]
>   cc1: error: unrecognized command line option
>   "-Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration" [-Werror] cc1: error:
>   unrecognized command line option "-Wno-unused-const-variable"
>   [-Werror] cc1: error: unrecognized command line option
>   "-Wno-absolute-value" [-Werror] cc1: error: unrecognized command line
>   option "-Wno-extended-offsetof" [-Werror] cc1: all warnings being
>   treated as errors make[4]: *** [yyscript.o] Error 1

if I run it with default clang to compile

> toolchain_build/toolchain_build_pnacl.py --verbose --clobber
>   --install toolchain/linux_x86/pnacl_newlib

then following error message is generated

> /home/albaforia/SVN/nativeclient/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang
>   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../src/binutils/gold  -I../../../src/binutils/gold -I../../../src/binutils/gold/../include -I../../../src/binutils/gold/../elfcpp -DLOCALEDIR="\"/share/locale\"" -DBINDIR="\"/bin\"" -DTOOLBINDIR="\"/arm-pc-nacl/bin\"" -DTOOLLIBDIR="\"/arm-pc-nacl/lib\""   -W -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wshadow -Werror -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -frandom-seed=yyscript.o -Wno-extended-offsetof -Wno-absolute-value -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-const-variable -Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration -Wno-unused-private-field -Wno-format-security -MT yyscript.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/yyscript.Tpo -c -o yyscript.o yyscript.c yyscript.c:1:1: error: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Werror,-Wimplicit-int] 
>       main() { return 0;
>   } ^~~~ 1 error generated. make[4]: *** [yyscript.o] Error 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the PNaCl toolchain builds with a downloaded binary of clang because Google's automated builders run Ubuntu 12.04, and the gcc on those systems cannot build recent versions of LLVM. So there are 2 options:
If you used Chromium's `depot_tools` to get the Native Client sources, you can easily get a copy of the same compiler the builders use: from the parent directory of `native_client` run
`tools/clang/scripts/update.sh` which will download and install clang in the directory where `toolchain_build_pnacl.py` expects it. Once it is installed, it will be kept up to date automatically by Native Clients `DEPS` hooks if you use `gclient` from `depot_tools`.

Otherwise you can use the system gcc to compile the PNaCl toolchain using the `--gcc` option. This should definitely work on Ubuntu 14.04 as that the system we develop PNaCl on.

As an aside I've started another [document](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/nativeclient/pnacl/building-pnacl-components-for-distribution-packagers) that has a few more details on the build process (even if its focus isn't exactly what you are interested in) and of course there is the `-h` flag of `toolchain_build_pnacl.py` and its sources.

Comment: Thanks for helping me a lot. tools/clang/scripts/update.sh gets the correct version of clang! But the build still fails. Even use with --gcc instead of clang.

Comment: Can you post the error message? At this point it's a completely different question from the one you originally asked though; I don't know if you should just mark this one as answered and start a new one, or just edit the original question or what...

Comment: I updated it this time. And if this problem still goes to another, I will make a new Question for it and reference to this. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Could you post more information on what the error is? You probably need to scroll up a bit (the errors are interleaved with other parts of the build because it builds in parallel). To help debug this you could also run toolchain_build/toolchain_build_pnacl.py on specific targets and reduce the amount of building that goes on, e.g. you could do:

```
toolchain_build/toolchain_build_pnacl.py llvm_x86_64_linux --verbose --install toolchain/linux_x86/pnacl_newlib
```

FYI, when you re-run the toolchain_build/toolchain_build_pnacl.py script you don't need to re-specify --sync and --clobber.

You can also run the make command manually as you debug the issue. In any case we'd like to fix the issue you're running into!

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I found that it is caused by missing of the llvm compilier.
I edited my question with adding more information of the Error Message.

Answer (score 1):

To use system compiler instead of compiler from `third_party/llvm_build/...` you may want to pass the `--gcc` option to the build script. Though, it's still unlikely that you'll succeed in building toolchain under Ubuntu 14.04.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and in order to build pnacl toolchain I have set up Ubuntu 12.04 [chroot environment](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebootstrapChroot). Inside it I can successfully build the toolchain using the following commands:

```bash
# get sources for NaCl itself
gclient config http://src.chromium.org/native_client/trunk/src/native_client@13992 --name native_client
gclient sync -j16

cd native_client
# sync sources for binutils, llvm, etc.
toolchain_build/toolchain_build_pnacl.py --verbose --sync-only
# build and install toolchain
toolchain_build/toolchain_build_pnacl.py --verbose --gcc --install install_dir
```

**PS:** I mount `/proc`, `/dev`, `/dev/pts`, `/sys`, `/run`, `/run/shm`, `/tmp` into my chroot environment and everything runs smoothly. Without mounting some of these directories some build scripts may fail, though I'm not sure about it.

Comment: Thanks for your help:)
And...yes, it still goes wrong when passing --gcc to it as you said.
I'll change try to change my system to Ububtu 12.04 later and build it again.

Comment: I did some effort to change my system to be similar to the one as you described. But it still not work. Would you please tell me more specific detail of your system? Including hardware, OS system of host and chroot environment, or something might be important to say. Thanks in advance.

Comment: My host system is Ubuntu 14.04 (amd64). Chroot system is Ubuntu 12.04 (amd64). CPU is i7-2600, though I don't think hw is important here. It's difficult to guess what went wrong in your case without error messages. May be you lacks some packages installed in chroot.