# What environment or package should be setup before building the pnacl toolchain

Tags: build, development-environment, environment, google-nativeclient, toolchain

[11/05 update]
The problem is solved hours after i posted it by myself. If you are looking for the answer, hope the following information helps.

------------------Original message--------------------

This question is going to be two parts:

1. What OS system should be used?
   there are many choice for developing pnacl, but what is the best or stable one.
2. What package should be installed?

   this question is referenced to the question I asked before, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609252/how-to-build-pnacl-toolchain)

   Until now, I'm not able to build it successfully.

   From my experience, I don't think this compilation error is come from pnacl it's self, since every compilation error I solved is by installing some package that I don't installed. And at least, there is a person who [successfully installed it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609252/how-to-build-pnacl-toolchain)

   ex : texinfo, clang, bison...

Here is the package I installed from the beginning(after ubuntu installed) till now :

```
g++
gcc-multilib
g++-multilib
libsdl1.2-dev
texinfo
libcrypto++-dev
libssl-dev
lib32ncurses5-dev m4
libelf-dev
bison
git
gitk
git-core
bision
clang
cmake
subversion
```

---

Comment: Feel free to add your answer and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by installing

```
byacc
flex
gyp
```

then it starts to build successfully